# OperationalError: no such table: students

Tags: python, html, sqlite, templates, flask

As a beginner, I have been trying the tutorial at tutorialpoint for flask at url: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlite.htm.

However, after this error

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
TemplateNotFound: home.html

Which should show:
 1. Add new record 
 2. Show List

I did the following:

```
  <h3>Students (<a href = "{{ url_for('new_student') }}">Add new record
     </a>)</h3>

   <h3> (<a href = "{{ url_for('list') }}">Show List
     </a>)</h3>
```

However, I think there may be other errors.

Now, I am getting the following error:

```
  sqlite3.OperationalError
  OperationalError: no such table: students
```

Could anyone help make the tutorial work? Much appreciated.
*ps: Please do not flag down this post. If you can't or do not want to help. Just leave this question to people who are willing to help beginners. Thank you.

Ref:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlite.htm

Here are the copy and paste as requested by @Wayne:

‘student.html’ :

```
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "{{ url_for('addrec') }}" method = "POST">
         <h3>Student Information</h3>
         Name<br>
         <input type = "text" name = "nm" /></br>

         Address<br>
         <textarea name = "add" ></textarea><br>

         City<br>
         <input type = "text" name = "city" /><br>

         PINCODE<br>
         <input type = "text" name = "pin" /><br>
         <input type = "submit" value = "submit" /><br>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

result.html:

```
<!doctype html>

    <html>
       <body>

          result of addition : {{ msg }}
          <h2><a href = "\">go back to home page</a></h2>

       </body>
    </html>
```

list.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <table border = 1>
         <thead>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Address>/td<
            <td>city</td>
            <td>Pincode</td>
         </thead>

         {% for row in rows %}
            <tr>
               <td>{{row["name"]}}</td>
               <td>{{row["addr"]}}</td>
               <td> {{ row["city"]}}</td>
               <td>{{row['pin']}}</td>  
            </tr>
         {% endfor %}
      </table>

      <a href = "/">Go back to home page</a>

   </body>
</html>
```

Flask-SQLite application:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3 as sql
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
   return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/enternew')
def new_student():
   return render_template('student.html')

@app.route('/addrec',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def addrec():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      try:
         nm = request.form['nm']
         addr = request.form['add']
         city = request.form['city']
         pin = request.form['pin']

         with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
            cur = con.cursor()

            cur.execute("INSERT INTO students (name,addr,city,pin) 
               VALUES (?,?,?,?)",(nm,addr,city,pin) )

            con.commit()
            msg = "Record successfully added"
      except:
         con.rollback()
         msg = "error in insert operation"

      finally:
         return render_template("result.html",msg = msg)
         con.close()

@app.route('/list')
def list():
   con = sql.connect("database.db")
   con.row_factory = sql.Row

   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute("select * from students")

   rows = cur.fetchall();
   return render_template("list.html",rows = rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Please add enough of the rest of your code so you have a [mcve]

Comment: Make sure you created the students table and that the database file is the same. In case doubt, use an absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo on another code which should be clearly be stated to be run to set up the database. Run this first, and it should work now.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')  # formerly typo as 'databsae.db'
print "Opened database successfully";

conn.execute('CREATE TABLE students (name TEXT, addr TEXT, city TEXT, pin TEXT)')
print "Table created successfully";
conn.close()
```